# Проблема с обращением к numpy.array по индексу

Tags: python, numpy, print

Мега-глупый вопрос, почему у меня не получается обратится к элементу numpy.array'я через переменную, через константу всё тип топ `results[1]` например

```
import numpy
import random
import math

results = numpy.array([])

for i in range(1000):
    a = random.randint(0, 50)
    b = random.randint(0, 50)
    c = math.sqrt(a**2+b**2)
    if c%2==0:
        print("[",a,",",b,"],")
        results = numpy.append(results, c)

print("Answers:")
for i in range(1000):
    print(results[int(i)]) # <------------------------  Ошибка тута
```

Comment: а ошибка какая? Просто по сути у вас будет ошибка т.к. у вас в любом случае не все 1000 числе будут удовлетворять условию `c%2==0`

Comment: Так у вас в results же не 1000 значений, а всего 26.

Comment: 1 - у вас в массиве не 1000 элементов. 2 - зачем целое число приводить к целому типу? Оно же и так целое.

Comment: Да это и так понятно что там не 1000 будет, это я просто пример кинул, кстати спасибо за ответы)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы уже используете Numpy, то используйте его преимущества (используйте циклы, только когда это действительно необходимо):

```
import numpy as np

N = 1000
a = np.random.randint(0, 50, size=N)
b = np.random.randint(0, 50, size=N)
c = np.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)
idx = np.where(c%2 == 0)[0]

print(a[idx])
print(b[idx])
print(c[idx])
```

результат:

> ```
> [14 14  0]
> [48 48 26]
> [50. 50. 26.]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу списка по индексу, которого не существует - ошибка `IndexError`.

Измените на простой вывод элементов списка:

```
print("Answers:")
for i in results:
    print i
```